# How Do I Show images on Asp.Net Website with Linq Query?

Tags: linq-to-sql

i can add images without any problem to my website.with my below code..i am using linq and asp.net with c#....

```
ImageDatabaseDataContext imdb = new ImageDatabaseDataContext();
Dosyalar ds;
Katilimci kt;
protected void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.FileContent != null)
    {
        string dosyaAdi = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        byte[] icerik = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
        string dosyaTipi = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType;

        try
        {
            ds = new Dosyalar();
            kt = new Katilimci();
            kt.AdSoyad = txtAdSoyad.Text;
            kt.BolgeMudurlugu = txtBolgeMudurlugu.Text;
            kt.Gorevi = txtGorev.Text;
            kt.NoktaAd = txtNoktaAd.Text;
            kt.NoktaTuru = txtNoktaTuru.Text;
            imdb.Katilimcis.InsertOnSubmit(kt);
            imdb.SubmitChanges();
            int idsi = kt.KID;

            ds.DosyaAD = dosyaAdi;
            ds.DosyaICERIK = icerik;
            ds.DosyaTIP = dosyaTipi;
            ds.KID = idsi;
            imdb.Dosyalars.InsertOnSubmit(ds);

            imdb.SubmitChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblHataci.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

**here is my question..How do i show my images that i was saving on sql server?on asp.Net website with linq queries?**

Thanks for your answer...

Comment: Please replace the code in your question with a sample that is more narrowly-focused on the exact problem you're having. Among other things, I have no idea which image you're referring to.

Comment: he's probably talking about the posted file that's being saved into the database.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the solution to this question as long as you get the contents of the image from the database.  it doesnt depend on any linq-to-sql.

[Dynamically Rendering asp:Image from BLOB entry in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

`public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
{

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    using(Image image = GetImage(context.Request.QueryString["ID"]))
    {    
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}`

this code solves my question thank you.