# Asp.net mvc - trying to display images pulled from db \

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

//Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<FilmFestWeb.Models.ListVideosViewModel>"

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>ListVideos</h2>

    <% foreach(BusinessObjects.Video vid in Model.VideoList){%>
    <div class="videoBox">
           <%= Html.Encode(vid.Name) %>
           <img src="<%= vid.ThumbnailImage %>" />      
    </div>


    <%} %>

</asp:Content>
```

//ListVideosViewModel

```
public class ListVideosViewModel

{

    public IList<Video> VideoList { get; set; }

}
```

//Video

```
public class Video

{        

    public long VideoId { get; set; }

    public long TeamId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public string TeamMembers { get; set; }

    public string TranscriptFileName { get; set; }

    public string VideoFileName { get; set; }

    public int TotalNumRatings { get; set; }

    public int CumulativeTotalScore { get; set; }

    public string VideoUri { get; set; }

    public Image ThumbnailImage { get; set; }


}
```

I am getting the "red x" that I usually associate with image file not found.   I have verified that my database table shows  after the stored proc that uploads the image executes.   Any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

As i see you are using mvc use this look at the example imagedata is byte[] array and imagemimetype is a string this is an example of an action in your controller

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int ProductID)
{
  Product product = (from p in productsRepository.Products
  where p.ProductID == ProductID
   select p).First();
  return File(product.ImageData, product.ImageMimeType);
}
```

use this to show the image in the view

```
 <img src="<%= Url.Action("GetImage", "Products",
 new { Model.ProductID }) %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be returning an Image from you database. You will be getting a byte[]. My recommendation would be to create a ASP.NET Handler that returns images from the DB. Then you can link to the handler.

Look at this SO post for how to do that: [Dynamically Rendering asp:Image from BLOB entry in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help.  This is how I solved the issue (uses entlib 4.1)

```
public ThumbnailImage GetThumbnailImageByVideoId( long videoId )
{
    Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("Connection String");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ThumbnailImage img =  null;

    try
    {
        using (DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("usp_GetThumbnailImageByVideoId"))
        {
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "VideoId", DbType.Int64, videoId);                    
            db.LoadDataSet(cmd, ds, "Video");
        }

        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["Video"].Rows)
        {
            if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["ThumbnailImage"].ToString()))
            {
                byte[] b = dr["ThumbnailImage"] as byte[];
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(b);
                img = new ThumbnailImage();
                img.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                img.ContentType = dr["ImageContentType"].ToString();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return img;
}
```