# How to develope a signature generator in ASP.net / c# for board-signatures?

Tags: c#, asp.net

my goal is to develop a signature generator for board-signatures.

I have my database with a few information about characters in a online-game.
A user should get a image-link, and should be able to write it in there board-signature.
In the Image should be a link to my page and a few information from my database.

Here is an example, which I want to build for another online game:
http://www.zetbit.com/

How to do that in ASP.Net / C# / .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following steps:

1. Create an .ashx (Generic Handler) in your site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx
2. Use System.Drawing to load the background images: [Dynamically Rendering asp:Image from BLOB entry in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)
3. Draw the image text on them: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/TextOnImage.aspx
4. Set an Http Expires header with a reasonable amount of time to minimize requests to your site
5. Include a bit of html that includes an `<a href='..'>` tag around the image url that points to your ashx handler. (this is the part that users would copy and paste into their signature)