# Show Image on repeater control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, repeater

Work on C# ASP.NET. I have a problem with **repeater** control. I want to show images on a page that is stored in a database. I collect information from northwind database.

**Categories** table

**SQL syntax:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
    [CategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryName] [nvarchar](15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Description] [ntext] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Picture] [image] NULL)
```

On pageload **C# syntax :**

```
 NorthWindDataContext db = new NorthWindDataContext();
            List<Category> oList = new List<Category>();
            oList = db.Categories.ToList();
            Repeater1.DataSource = oList;
```

**aspx Syntax:**

```
 <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Picture")%>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

After run the code,in my page i don't get the picture.help me to get picture on my page .Thanks in advance .If have any query plz ask.

Comment: You're trying to output binary data onto the page. For an image to be displayed in HTML, you need to <img src="path to image"> Since that image is binary data, you'd likely have to set up a handler to server up that image data and then point to the handler in the source.

Answer (score 2):

You are store images as binary data in a data base so you can not show it as is.

[MSDN on `image` data type:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

> Variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)
>   bytes.

The common approach is to create  instance of the `System.Drawing.Image` from a memory stream and then write it explicitly inr response. This functionality should be wrapped by ASHX handler. See intrawebs for the examples, there are a lot.

Handler pseudo code below: (then in ASPX just reffer handler)

```
IEnuemrable<byte> binaryImageData = queryExecutor.GetImageData(imageId);

// do not forget to dispose or use 'using'
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(); 
memoryStream.Write(imageByte, 0, binaryImageData.Length);
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

// ... create JPEG

context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
jpegImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, 
               System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Good examples I've found:

- SO Post: [Dynamically Rendering asp:Image from BLOB entry in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)
- [C# Save and Load Image from Database](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ImageInDatabase.aspx)