# How to get the data and image from SQL in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a table in SQL and stored some fields image. When I want to retrieve the data and image, it's not working. I have stored the image by converting it into byte array. Will you please help me on how to retrieve the data and image into ASP webpage?

Comment: search on google thousands of article there for this

Comment: http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2007/05/save-and-restore-filesimages-to-sql.html

Comment: what code you use to convert the images to byte Array

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Read the byte array from blob (image) field and create a MemoryStream
2. Save that byte array or Write it to Response buffer.

You may create a [Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx) to [serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net) these images.

Comment: There is no reason to decode the bytes into an image just so save it again. Just serve the bytes.

Comment: @Guffa - Appreciate! Thanks for the suggestion.