# retrieve image from access DB and display in webpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I found an old article of an example of what I am trying to do (retrieve an image stored in a ms access Db and display on my aspx page).  Does anyone have a good example of this for vb.net?

[Old Article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/q175/2/61.asp&NoWebContent=1)

Answer (score 1):

You may write an Image [handler.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx) Take a look at Stackoverflow thread - [Dynamically Rendering asp:Image from BLOB entry in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)