# Open image saved in database with Internet explorer

Tags: c#

How I can open the image saved in database directly using Internet Explorer (Not WebBrowser control in WinForm/WPF) without saving it to a file first?

Comment: You have tagged this question to C#, where is C# involved here? Is it that you want a code in C# to get the image from DB and display it in a Web Browser?

Comment: Yes, the code I needed is in C#. I can get the image from database in byte[] format but I don't know how to display it using Internet Explorer, not the "WebBrowser" control. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically Rendering asp:Image from BLOB entry in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)

Comment: Is it ASP.Net or WinForm/WPF??

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible unless you create a web page or something similar to display the image from a temp file

Comment: Not true, you just need a handler which returns the byte[] with correct content type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Search for Process.Start look at the site...
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

This gives you the exact example of opening a file in IE, you might need to save your image into a temp file on the disk