# Web server instances?

Tags: asp.net

Very newbie question, please forgive me:

I'm creating an asp.net website.  I assume that when multiple people request the page each person gets a new instance of the site.  However, if the site uses a .jpg image on the server and manipulates the image, does each person get an instance of the image also, or do they share the image somehow?  I think I know, and that this is probably a dumb question, but I wanted to ask.

As an example: A user logs into the site, and adds times to a schedule.  Depending on the schedule, a blue line is drawn on an image (grid.jpg), which depicts a daily timeline.  The image is then saved as newgrid.jpg and displayed to the user.  Is there a way for each user to get an instance of the image that only they can see?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking, could you elaborate?

Comment: You deploy a site to a folder on a server. You create a site in IIS. All requests/users share the same site. If you made changes to physical files served up by this site, all users see the changes. If you want to isolate users so they can't see other peoples changes you would use Session data or some other persistant storage for seperating users or implement some sort of directory structure so that User X has his own content and User Y their own.

Comment: @Nick Is that something I do in the site code, or is that something I do when I deploy the site on the server?

Comment: @JakeGaston : That is something you have to take care of yourself; yes, in your code!

Comment: @Styxxy I was afraid of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great way to generate dynamic images in ASP.NET is by using a `Handler`. The answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net) offers a good, simple example. In this scenario, the generated image never touches the local file system, it's just generated in memory, and returned to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think this might guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually the site is always the same for all users, but there are sessions created for each user with specific settings that you can set. So yes, all people will by default see the same changes (and the same content).