# Display image in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

During display of an image from database in the gridview control, the following error occurred: `Parameter is not valid`

The following code displays the image:

```
        var id = Convert.ToString(user_id);

        var category = (from data in db.Register1_db
                        where (data.User_ID == id)
                       select ( data.Student_Photo));

        int len = category.First().Length;
        // Output the binary data          
        // But first we need to strip out the OLE header          
        int OleHeaderLength = 78;
        int strippedImageLength = len - OleHeaderLength;
        byte[] imagdata = new byte[strippedImageLength];          
        Array.Copy(category.First().ToArray(), OleHeaderLength, imagdata, 0, strippedImageLength);          
        if ((imagdata) != null)          
        {              
            MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(imagdata);

                //error occurred               
            System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(m);              
            image.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);          
        }
```

Comment: How are you executing this code?  This would work if its a handler, but not if it's defined in the page code behind.  Also where in the code is this happening?

Comment: This is one, of many reasons, why most developers store images outside the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to display image in a gridview is using Image handlers. 
[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net)

Comment: Trying to get an answer to my issue here. I have two images which I want to display in a grid which displays students. One of the image will be displayed depending on whether a student is enrolled or not, This view I have is strongly typed, how can I get this to work?