# bind database image to ItemTemplate in .ascx

Tags: asp.net, database, listview, data-binding, itemtemplate

I am using dynamic ItemTemplate for ListView which populated from database.Here is how I do when I need to display string column "Parametr" (or some other datatypes):

```
     //my .ascx file
     <li><%# Eval("Parametr") %> </li>
```

How can I display varbinary column that stores images?Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Here is some more code if somebody needed:

```
<asp:ListView ...  DataSourceID="database"   ></asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ... ID="database" SelectCommand="SELECT image FROM image_table"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Here is a solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an "inline image". The technique is described at for instance [Base64 encoded images embedded in html](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html) (search for base64 image html for other resources).

Get the base64-encoded string of the image data bytes, using [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) for instance, and then use `<img src=data:image/gif;base64,` and append the image data.

So you can bind it using something like this

```
<img src='<%# string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}",
 Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageDataBase64")))%>'/>
```

Of course, this is only recommended for small images. Also note that you should change "gif" to the actual format of your image.

Comment: @AntonPutov: That's unfortunate. Unfortunately I can't help you, since you won't tell me what the problem is.

Comment: my problem is simple - here is template [<li><img alt="some text" src='<%# string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}",Eval("blob"))%>'/></li>] - blob - binary image data (gif).its not work).Are there another ways to solve this problem?

Comment: What? The problem could be "InvalidOperationException", or "SqlException". I can't believe the error you are seeing on your web page is "It doesn't work"?

Comment: What is "blob" in your example?

Comment: @AntonPutov: What is blob then? If you inspect the code, do you have any text after the `,` in the image source?

Comment: I can't help you if all you keep saying is "it doesn't work", you have to specify the problem you are facing. *Why does it not work*?

Comment: I edit my question - blob is varbinary column which saves image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18421/discussion-between-anton-putov-and-patrick)

Comment: Again, you have to convert it to a base64 string first, you can't use a byte array as the argument to the string format method, because it won't work, as described in the answer