# #Eval image data

Tags: asp.net, image, eval

How can I use Eval for binding sql varbinary data (images) to image?
Something like this:

```
   <image src = <%# Eval("imageBinaryData") %> />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a HttpHandler to fetch the data and stream it back. You would then link to the handler from your ASPX page.

```
<img class="mainEventsImage" 
    src='<%# Eval("MainImagePath").ToString().Replace("\\", "/") %>' 
        alt='<%# Eval("Title") %>' runat="server" />

if (reader.Read())
{
    int bufferSize = 100;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
    long bytesRead;
    long readFrom = 0;

    do
    {
        bytesRead = reader.GetBytes(0, readFrom, bytes, 0, bufferSize);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        readFrom += bufferSize;
    }
    while (bytesRead == bufferSize);
}
reader.Close();
```

Comment: i want to do it like this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002578/bind-database-image-to-itemtemplate-in-ascx/13002874#comment17666856_13002874

Comment: It won't work without some major workarounds. Example in answer is the normal way to accomplish this. Similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+image+handler

Comment: your link save me a lot of time.thanks a lot.Here is I like more:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877/dynamically-rendering-aspimage-from-blob-entry-in-asp-net